# Intent give error when working with Line Graph, Bar Graph, Scatter Graph and Pie Graph example

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I have an following error occur when I run the each of the graph

Error log:

```
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
```

Then show the eroor log:

```
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): at com.example.graph.PieGraph.getIntent(PieGraph.java:18)
10-25 06:00:46.555: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): at com.example.graph.MainActivity.pieGraphHandler(MainActivity.java:31)
```

The class for a Pie Graph is:

package com.example.graph;

```
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class PieGraph {

public Intent getIntent(Context context)
{
    int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5};

    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pie Graph");
    int k = 0;
    for(int value: values) {
        series.add("Section " + ++k, value);
    }

    int[] colors = new int[] {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN};

    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for(int color: colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, series, renderer, "Pie");
    return intent;
}
}
```

Main Activity is:

```
package com.example.graph;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void lineGraphHandler(View view) {
    LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = line.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);

}
public void barGraphHandler(View view) {
    BarGraph bar = new BarGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = bar.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);

}
public void pieGraphHandler(View view) {
    PieGraph pie = new PieGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = pie.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);

}
public void scatterGraphHandler(View view) {
    ScatterGraph scatter = new ScatterGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = scatter.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I have add the jar file of achartengine as achartengine-1.1.0.jar to the project and I have also add in my AndroidManifest.Xml :

```
 <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"></activity>
```

when I click the each of graph as Line graph, bar graph, scatter graph and pie graph, it gives me same type of error. Can Anyone please tell me what is the problem here? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check again to make sure you really added the AChartEngine library to your classpath. If you are using an IDE then a project clean / refresh may help.